# Use SVG tag in <img> tag src with animation

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg

Is it possible to use `<svg>` tag in `<img>` tag src attribute?
If yes, can I use animated svg under same?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use the full fledged <svg> tag inside src attribute, but sure you can use inline svg source for an image. See:http://depth-first.com/articles/2011/10/19/display-inline-svg-using-the-img-tag/

Comment: Sure it's possible but only via SMIL (or possibly CSS animation) i.e. javascript animation is not possible.